# Getting a mup setup error (AWS EC2 instance)

Tags: meteor, amazon-ec2, telescope

I am trying to setup a simple Telescope Meteor app on an AWS EC2 instance and I am getting an error message when trying to run mup setup:

Here is my mup.json file:

```
 {
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "ec2-54-191-197-203.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
      "username": "ubuntu",
      //"password": "password"
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      //"pem": "/Users/apple/Coding/Contract Work/TelescopeApp.pem"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.36 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.36",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Show a progress bar during the upload of the bundle to the server.
  // Might cause an error in some rare cases if set to true, for instance in Shippable CI
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "TelescopeApp",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "/Users/apple/Coding/Contract Work",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://ec2-54-191-197-203.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "MONGO_URL" "mongodb://localhost:27017/Telescope-database"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/node_modules/cjson/index.js:226
        throw err;
        ^

SyntaxError: Trailing comma in object at 10:5
    }
    ^
File: "/Users/apple/Coding/Contract Work/Telescope/mup.json"
    at SyntaxError (native)
    at Object.parseJSON (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/node_modules/jju/lib/parse.js:745:13)
    at Object.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/node_modules/json-parse-helpfulerror/index.js:10:13)
    at Object.exports.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/node_modules/cjson/index.js:90:28)
    at Object.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/node_modules/cjson/index.js:223:24)
    at Object.exports.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/lib/config.js:12:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/bin/mup:20:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `mupx`. It's the stable version.

Comment: With `mupx` I can run setup but on deploy I get the same error message.

Comment: does this project run on your local machine?

Comment: And the error clearly points out that your `mup.json` file has trailing `}` missing on line 10. fix this issue before you try to deploy

Comment: That `}` in line 10 was fine. I uncommented the `.pem` line `      "pem": "/Users/apple/Coding/Contract Work/TelescopeApp.pem"` and it worked but now I have the following error message when using `mupx``Error: spawn meteor ENOENT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
"username": "ubuntu",
```

to

```
"username": "ubuntu"
```

---

You probably commented the `"password: "password"` line and forgot to remove the additional comma after `"username": "ubuntu",`.